# Exchange 2010 and Outlook SSL Error

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook

I have a new setup of windows SBS. When I connect via outlook I get a message that the SSL for "remote.mail.*mydomain.com*" does not match.

I setup the SSL for "mail.*mydomain.com*". I can't find where to change the URL that outlook should use. I know it would be an exchange setting, but I've been through all the screens and I can't find it.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you're looking for the configuration option to set the external client URL that outlook or activesync devices use when accessing mail either through EWS or activesync.

To set this in exchange 2010 via the EMC (Exchange Management Console):

1. Open the EMC.
2. Expand the "Server Configuration" tree in the left hand pane.
3. Select the "Client Access" item under "Server Configuration"
4. In the Actions pane, located to the right of the window, now select "Configure External Client Access Domain" and follow the wizard:

[image]

I would also suggest creating an A record in your external and internal DNS servers pointing to your exchange server, this will allow for far easier configuration of your email clients.

Answer (score 1):

I would try [the PowerShell script located here](http://msunified.net/2010/05/07/script-for-configuring-exchange-2010-internal-and-external-urls/).

I'm a little tired at the moment, but what's left of my brain is telling me that this is one of those things in Exchange 2010 that can't be changed in the GUI and requires PowerShell.